# Generate CDATA inside of tag using StreamingMarkupBuilder

Tags: groovy, cdata

I need following structure in XML

```
<DCS>
    <bytes length="29235"><![CDATA[....]]></bytes>
</DCS>
```

And have following code

```
DCS {
bytes(length: "${docBytes.size()}",mkp.yieldUnescaped("<![CDATA[${docBytes}]]>"))
}
```

But it generate

```
   <DCS>
    <![CDATA[[....]]]>
<bytes length='135948'>groovy.xml.streamingmarkupsupport.StreamingMarkupWriter@32adca00</bytes>
    </DCS>
```

How can I generate required xml structure ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your `mkp.yieldUnescaped` in a closure, not just as the second parameter to the `bytes` tag method, ie:

```
import groovy.xml.*

byte[] docBytes = 'Tim Yates'

new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
  DCS {
    bytes( length:docBytes.length ) {
      mkp.yieldUnescaped "<![CDATA[${docBytes.toList().join(' ')}]]>"
    }
  }
}
```

Which generates:

```
<DCS><bytes length='9'><![CDATA[84 105 109 32 89 97 116 101 115]]></bytes></DCS>
```

You can see here, I've encoded each byte into a String separated by a space.  How you do it is up to you (and I guess depends on what is going to be decoding the bytes) ;-)