# Grails XML converters - write CDATA

Tags: grails

Is writing CDATA from GRAILS converters possible?  I have a requirement of writing CDATA for some XML elements in a GRAILS app.  After running through the grails code in debugger, it looks like the XMLStreamWriter is not accessible.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

there's no possibility to add cdata via xml converters. you can use StreamingMarkupBuilder:
[Generate CDATA inside of tag using StreamingMarkupBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929060/generate-cdata-inside-of-tag-using-streamingmarkupbuilder)

or, have a nice uglyhack, copying '.chars' method from groovy converter definition right in your code, writing chars unescaped:

```
converter.startNode('property')
converter.attribute('name', propertyName)
converter.startNode('value')
//converter.chars("<![CDATA[" + propertyValue + "]]>")
//as chars in xml converter go escaped, had to rewrite the method here: 
converter.checkState();
try {
    if (converter.writer.mode == TAG) {
        converter.writer.endStartTag();
    }
    converter.writer.mode = CONTENT;
    //we put the data unescaped:
    converter.writer.writer.unescaped().write("<![CDATA[" + propertyValue + "]]>");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    throw ConverterUtil.resolveConverterException(e);
}
//-----------------
converter.end()
converter.end()
```

Comment: this is gold

converter.writer.mode = CONTENT
converter.writer.writer.unescaped().write("<![CDATA[" + propertyValue + "]]>")

BTW the CONTENT is org.grails.web.xml.XMLStreamWriter.Mode.CONTENT